# discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set in the standard topology.
And let $V\subseteq U$ be a discrete sub-set.
Is $V$ necessarily countable? how can I prove it?

Answer (score 4):

For any $v \in V$ consider a box $B_v = (a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2)$ with rational ends  so that $B_v \cap V= v$.  We get an injective map from $V$ to the set of rational boxes, which is countable.

Comment: so this only uses second countability, nice. The result holds even for non-Hausdorff spaces, i.e. discrete subsets of second countable spaces are countable.